# isset($_GET['variable']) not working?

Tags: php

This function is not working for me. I think it is isset($_GET['success']) that's not working but I'm really not sure. the problem is it doesn't print anything ever. And without if(isset($_GET['success'])) it only prints "username taken" Please help?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
$success=$_GET['success'];
if($success=='yes') {
echo "<center><font color='red'>Comment Posted!</font></center>";
}
else {
echo "<center><font color='red'>Username taken!</font></center>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what is happening?

Comment: Please define "not working". Errors? Doesn't it do what you want it to do?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: If nothing is getting echoed then there is probably an error. Find it in the logs or modify the code to produce it edit your post to include it.

Comment: You need to include the ?HTML form? that is submitting the GET request if you want any help with this one mate.

Comment: Moderator flags are for reporting serious issues, not for asking us to help answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of output are you getting from this? Are you passing the GET method correctly? the URL should have page_name.php?success=yes in it. If you're not getting anything and you want success to be only set if it is true perhaps this would be better.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success']=='yes') 
{
     echo "<center><font color='red'>Comment Posted!</font></center>";
}
else 
{
     echo "<center><font color='red'>Username taken!</font></center>";
}
?>
```