# $_GET variable not returning value when used in a search function in MVC designed code

Tags: php

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645532/isset-getvariable-not-working) but a little different. I am trying to create a search feature in my code. However when i use the $_GET variable i am not able to echo-out the search value entered.

Here is the code separated in 3 files(i am using a custom MVC design and not any particular framework)

Search form

```
<form action = "maina2/getStaffname" method = "get">
        <select name = "choice">
            <option value = "staffname" name = "staffname">title</option>
            <option value = "id" name = "id"> author</option>

        </select>
            <input name= "search" type ="text"  size="65" maxlength = "88" style = "display:inline">
            <input name = "mysearch" type="submit"  style = "display:inline">
</form>
```

The search controller

```
<?php

    class Search extends Controller {
        public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        }

        function Index() {
            $this->view->getStaffname = $this->model->getStaffname();
            $this->view->render('search/index');

        }

        function getStaffname() {
            $this->model->getStaffname();

        }
    }
```

And this is the search model file

```
<?php

class Search_Model extends Model{
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        echo 'This is the SEARCH MODEL CLASS <br />';

    }

    public function getStaffname(){
        if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
                echo $_GET['search'];

        }
    }
}
```

What surprices me is that when i change the method to POST then i am able to echo out the search value. What might be wrong with my technique?

Comment: The issue might be inside your routing handlers which are not shown here. Are you sure you map `GET` request to the method that is called by `POST`?

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using? If it is custom framework check how it handles request

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain It is a custom MVC.

Comment: 1. The problem is likely in your .htaccess in the way you rewrite requests, probably discarding query parameters in the process. 2. It's the controller's job to get the input and pass it on to the model, you should not be hardcoding `$_GET` inside your model.

Comment: How do you mean .htaccess might be the problem @deceze?

Comment: How does the URL `maina2/getStaffname` get translated to your `Search` controller…? There's probably some form of .htaccess file involved, no?

Comment: yes there is. The rewriterule looks like this `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1`. Do you reckon this as the problem? Why is it when i change the method to  'POST' in the form and use `$_POST['search']` in the controller i am able to echo out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The rewriterule looks like this `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1`

You're replacing all your query parameters with one `url` parameter; if there was any `?search=...` in the URL before, it's not going to be there afterwards. You want to preserve existing parameters with [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

> Why is it when i change the method to 'POST' in the form and use `$_POST['search']` in the controller i am able to echo out?

Because the request body ("POST parameters") isn't being affected by the rewrite rule.

Comment: It works. I had overlooked the query string append[QSA] parameter. Thank you.